# How to hide dependent Edittextpreferences when a Checkboxpreference is checked?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a *CheckBoxPreference* and two *EditTextPreferences* which are dependent on the *CheckBoxPreference* (all defined in an xml file and all three together inside a single *PreferenceScreen*).

My question is this: How to **hide** and **redisplay** those two *EditTextPreferences* when the user **unchecks** and **checks** the *Checkboxpreference* respectively?

Currently I am just able to *enable/disable* them by adding the **android:dependency** attribute to them.

Solutions to do so in **java** or in **xml** will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anyway to do this through xml, which always my preferred choice. But this java solution should work.

```
CheckBoxPreference chkPref = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("myCheckPref");
EditTextPreference editPref1 = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("myEditCheckPref");
PreferenceGroup editTextParent = getParent(editPref1);

chkPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener(){

public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference pref, Object value)
{
   if(value)
      editTextParent.addPreference(editPref1);
   else
      editTextParent.removePreference(editPref1);

return true;
}

});
```

As there is no in built way to find the parent group of a parent, you will also have to define these functions:

```
private PreferenceGroup getParent(Preference preference)
{
    return getParent(getPreferenceScreen(), preference);
}

private PreferenceGroup getParent(PreferenceGroup root, Preference preference)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < root.getPreferenceCount(); i++)
    {
        Preference p = root.getPreference(i);
        if (p == preference)
          return root;
       if (PreferenceGroup.class.isInstance(p))
       {
        PreferenceGroup parent = getParent((PreferenceGroup)p, preference);
        if (parent != null)
            return parent;
    }
}
  return null;
}
```

Comment: You rock :) Thanks a lot man :) I had tried something similar to this sans the PreferenceGroup :) Though I understood your code, can u explain a little bit about why you need this parent and preferencegroup? Is it that if I add a dependency, the dependent node is the child of the other node?